# Laravel 5.3 - Avoid sending slack notification in phpunit test

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

So I've got a test set up that visits the sign up page and submits the form. Then the test verifies the account by token.

Once the account has been verified, a notification is sent through a   `SlackMessage`.

What I was wondering is how can I intercept this, and stop the slack message from actually sending - only when running a test, but get some kind of confirmation that the notification did in fact get called.

Comment: Can't you mock the notification sending class?

Comment: I guess I could. Never knew mockery even existed. Well I have a bunch of new things to do :) I'm quite new to testing. Ended up with doing Notification::shouldReceive('send')->once();  which seems to work quite well. Thanks :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found an undocumented method expectsNotifications() in the Laravel 5.3 MockApplicationServices trait. It works pretty much the same as the [documented event mocking](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/mocking#mocking-events).

Usage is:

```
$this->expectsNotification($notifiable, $notification);

// eg.
$this->expectsNotification($user, UpperLimitExceeded::class);
```

There is also $this->withoutNotifications() to skip over any encountered notifications.

Comment: This is literally the only reference to `expectsNotification` I was able to find. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

If you need to skip sending all notifications, put the following line at the beginning of your test method:

`$this->withoutNotifications();`

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just doing `Notification::shouldReceive('send')->once();` for anyone who's wondering. Which I guess is the correct way to mock the Notification facade :)